# UITableViewCell subclass all constraints gone at runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have a `UITableViewCell` subclass as normal, and have some views/outlets/constraints:

[image]

I can assure you there's nothing special here. An image view and two labels, related by regular horizontal/center Y constraints, and the image view has leading/top constraints. Pretty simple and regular stuff.

However, when I run, I get this:

[image]

Image (I've also tried with different background color, it's there at top left of the cell, just with a white background) and the both labels are stuck at the top left of the cell. I've been programming iOS/autolayout for years and this is the first time I'm seeing such a thing.

There aren't any broken constraints on the log either. When I open view debugger, I see this:

[image]

While all the size constraints are there, all the superview/inter-view constraints are gone and they are being reported as "position ambiguous". The constraints are not even there. Why would this happen? I've double checked the constraints in Interface Builder: they are at 1000 priority, are installed, and are *not* placeholders:

[image]

Moreover, I've got other cells (with slightly different design) that inherit from the same class, and they are perfectly working with a different nib. In fact, I've directly copied the cell from another nib so it's the replica of a perfectly one either.

What would be going wrong?

Comment: Did you try to change your image view's width/height constraints from 1000 to 999? Auto Layout can be *very* picky about those, especially in a table view cell. [See this Apple doc page about debugging auto layout issues.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/DebuggingTricksandTips.html)

Comment: Do you use `Size Classes` here?

Comment: @the4kman tried it. nothing changes. as I've said it doesn't seem to be breaking any constraints anyway.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @vrwim to be honest I gave up autolayout on this one as I didn't need it as everything was visually anchored to top-left.